# jquery-mobile supported browser list (for use in .htaccess)?

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent, jquery-mobile

I need to use my .htaccess file to redirect the users to a [jquery-mobile](http://jquerymobile.com)-powered version of my site. For technical reasons, I can't rely on doing the redirect using php or ruby or any other language.

So I'm basically trying to translate [the list of jquery-mobile supported browsers](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) to something a bit more condensed user-agent list (maybe a regexp).

Does such a list / regexp exist?

**Note**: I'm looking for a way to answer yes/no to the question "Is the user using a jquery-mobile-supported browser?" Please **don't** answer with generic browser identifiers/lists, such as [wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) or [zyntrax's mobile list](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html), unless they include a jquery-mobile specific section.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full browser list jquerymobile supports

http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

sorry, but I do not have regex

Comment: I already knew about that list. It is actually linked on the question. I wanted to know about a more explicit list (at least with the user agents used ...)